# What does JList.getSelectedIndices() actually return?

Tags: java, swing

Apparently, JList.getSelectedIndices()  returns an array of int values for the indices of the selected items.

I have searched around the internet for what would indices mean in this scenario. I'm not able to find an answer, so could someone please explain its uses and what it actually returns?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: What are you trying? Do you want to know about `JList.getSelectedIndices()` only or using it somewhere in your code?

Comment: The javadoc isn't very noob friendly.                               Returns an array of all of the selected indices, in increasing order.
Returns:
all of the selected indices, in increasing order, or an empty array if nothing is selected

Comment: @Braj I want to know about it, because my book vaguely explained it.

Comment: It's same as `JList#getSelectedIndex()` method. The only difference is that what type of `ListSelectionModel` is used? If its a Multi-Selection then use `getSelectedIndices()` to get all the selected item's index.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it returns a list of selected indices because technically it's valid to select more than one element from the JList.

Take the example given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#selection)

[image: example 1] selected indices here would be {1}

[image: example 2] selected indices here would be {1, 2, 3}

[image: example 3] selected indices here would be {0, 1, 3}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What exactly is an indice? I am assuming it is when an element is addressed by its index value.

Comment: the index is pretty much what address the element is at in the model, with 0 being the first element and (length-1) usually being the last. So for instance, if you added the words "hello", "world", and "foo" to your JList's model, "hello" would have an index of 0, "world" would have an index of 1, and "foo" would have an index of 2

Comment: Thank you for the explanation once again.

Comment: @user3758041 there's no such thing as one indice - "indices" is the traditional plural of "index" in English, though "indexes" is becoming more common in some situations. Personally I tend to use indices when I'm talking about the mathematical concept of an index into an array or something, but indexes when I'm talking about the index in a search engine or the back of a book.